# Upload file to media folder during AJAX instead of when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, amazon-s3

I've just got a simple upload form:

```
def post(request):    
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user

            instance.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')
        else:
            form_post = PostForm()

        context = {
            'form_post': form_post,
        }
        return render(request, 'post/post.html', context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/signup/")
```

which derives from here:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'title',
            'image',
            'user'
        ]
```

and here's the models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=95)
    image = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
```

When a user adds an image to the form, it fires this JS function:

```
$('input#id_image').on('change', function(e) {...}
```

which gives a preview of the image. This is the point where I want the image to be uploaded to my media folder directory (I'm using S3 storage). By default, the image is uploaded when the user submits the form, but I want it to be uploaded as soon as `$('input#id_image').on('change'` is triggered.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Just send your form as ajax request in your onChange handler:

```
$('input#id_image').on('change', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "your endpoint here",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData($(form#yourFormID)[0])             
        }).done(function(data) {
           //on success code
        }).fail(function(data, err) {
           //on fail code
        }).always(function() {
           //whatever to be done no matter if success or error
        });

}
```

Comment: Sweet so this sends it from my JS to my Django views - however I'm not sure what to do from there. Because when I submit the form previously, it automatically uploads to my media directory, but now I have to do it manually. `def upload_image(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        img = request.FILES.get('image')` - not sure what to do after this